# Structuring modules, models in Nodejs with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm creating basic NodeJS/Express?MongoDb app. I have api module (controller) that basically checks the path and tells models to do things:

api.js

```
var users = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function(app, u) {

    app.get('/api/v1/users/get-all', function(req, res, next) {

        res.json({
            users: users.getAll()
        });
    });
};
```

Users is another module that represents model. getAll method is called from api module and reads data from MongoDb:

users.js

```
Users = function() {

    Users.prototype.getAll = function(req, res, next) {

        var cursor = this.db.users.find();

        // return all the users as json

        cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
            return items;
        });

    }

    Users.prototype.setDb = function(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
};

module.exports = new Users();
```

I only realised that MongoDB this.db.users.find() call is asynchronous and so when getAll comes back from users module, my API module with res.json(..) got empty result to work with.

Now, I was thinking that one option would be to pass res. object from api module to users, and users would respond with data back to client when data would be ready:

api.js

```
var users = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function(app, u) {

    app.get('/api/v1/users/get-all', function(req, res, next) {

        users.getAll(res)

    });
};
```

users.js

```
Users = function() {

    Users.prototype.getAll = function(res) {

        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa " + this.db);
        var cursor = this.db.users.find();

        // return all the users as json

        cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.json({
                users: items
            });
        });

    }

    Users.prototype.setDb = function(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
};

module.exports = new Users();
```

This seems to work however if I understand correctly model should not have to do anything twith this sort of work, returning stuff to client etc.

Then I thought about using promises for this and this what I came up with:

api.js

```
var users = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function(app, u) {

    app.get('/api/v1/users/get-all', function(req, res, next) {

        users.getAll().then(function(res) {
            console.log("u=users " + (res));
            res.json({
                users: res
            });
        });
    });

};
```

users.js

```
var Q = require("q");

Users = function() {

    Users.prototype.getAll = function(req, res, next) {

        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa " + this.db);
        var cursor = this.db.users.find();

        // return all the users as json

        return new Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
                resolve(items);
            });

        });
    }

    Users.prototype.setDb = function(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
};

module.exports = new Users();
```

I love the simplicity of promises and wanted to know if there is any obvious flaw in my implementation in how the modules are taking to each other rather than in details.

Comment: There is no obvious flow. The only thing I'd change is getAll should _not_ accept the request/response/next (like you said - it should be abstracted from it). You can also convert a whole API into promises immediately with `promisifyAll` if you use a better promise library like Bluebird instead of Q. Other than that - questions on how to improve working code belong on CodeReview.StackExchange.com and not StackOverflow .

Comment: I meant "flaw" there, not "flow".